# tkinter oo - how to iconify a top-level window linking to a button widget

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I am working with python 3.8, macos Big Sur.

```py
from tkinter import *

def test(window):
    window.iconify()

def onclick():
    window = Toplevel()
    window.geometry("+300+300")
    window.title("child window")
    Button(window, text="click", command=lambda: test(window)).pack()
    window.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.title("parent window")
root.geometry("300x200+200+200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.iconbitmap("tools.ico")

Button(root, text="open child window", command=onclick).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to rewrite the code above as a class, like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('title')
        self.root.geometry("300x200+500+250")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.interface()
        self.root.iconbitmap("tools.ico")

    def interface(self):
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="open child window", command=self.onclick).pack()

    def onclick(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry('200x100+500+250')
        window.title('child window')
        self.btn = tk.Button(window, text="click", command=lambda window: self.test(*window)).pack()

        window.mainloop()

    def test(self, window):
        window.iconify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
    gui.root.mainloop()
```

however, it ends with

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'
```

I also have tried binding an iconify event with button, like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('title')
        self.root.geometry("300x200+500+250")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.interface()
        self.root.iconbitmap("tools.ico")

    def interface(self):
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="open child window", command=self.onclick).pack()

    def onclick(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry('200x100+500+250')
        window.title('child window')
        self.btn = tk.Button(window, text="click")
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.test(window=window))

        window.mainloop()

    def test(self, window):
        window.iconify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
    gui.root.mainloop()
```

just did not work either.

I would appreciate if anyone point out how I could work with `lambda: window` in the first example code given above.

==2022/8/13==:

```py
class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('title')
        self.root.geometry("300x200+500+250")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.interface()
        self.root.iconbitmap("tools.ico")

    def interface(self):
        btnopen = tk.Button(self.root, text="open child window", command=self.onclick).pack()

    def onclick(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry('200x100+500+250')
        window.title('child window')
        btnclick = tk.Button(window, text="click", command=lambda: self.test(window)).pack()

        window.mainloop()

    def test(self, window):
        window.iconify()
        window.deiconify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
    gui.root.mainloop()
```

pass with the code above...
a low class mistake I made is that I defined 2 self.btn. Besides, it should work with `lambda: self.test(window)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is `iconify()` the window then why not just use that in the command?  No need to separate it as its own method.  Is this what you are looking for?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('title')
        self.root.geometry("300x200+500+250")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.interface()
        #self.root.iconbitmap("tools.ico")

    def interface(self):
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="open child window", command=self.onclick)
        self.btn.pack()

    def onclick(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry('200x100+500+250')
        window.title('child window')
        self.btn = tk.Button(window, text="click", command=lambda: window.iconify())
        self.btn.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
    gui.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if we do more things than just iconify in 'test' function, how should I work with lambda in 'command' ?

Comment: @missmango `lambda` is generally used to pass parameters with the function.  It is basically an anonymous function.(You aren't predefining it like when you normally use `def my_func`) Maybe [these examples will help clarify it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/)